# removing template after rendering when no longer in scope of same view

Tags: backbone.js

I have a link (with class .story) in a navbar, which, if clicked, renders a story template into a canvas div to provide information to the user. I want to give the user the option to remove the template after reading the info, however, I can't set a click event on the delete "x" in the template.

I think I know the problem. My StoryView el is the `<div id="story">` so I can set events on anything within that, but since it renders into another div not attached to that view, I can't remove it from that view.

Here's a fiddle showing the problem. Update, I had included the wrong fiddle. Fixed now.

http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/RRXnK/145/

Html

```
<div id="story">
   <a href="#" class="story">click this story link to render into canvas_id but how to set event to remove?</a>
</div>

<div id="canvas_id"></div>
```

View

```
var StoryView = Backbone.View.extend({

  el: $("#story"),

   events: {
      'click .story': 'render', 
       'click .delete': 'test'

    },

     initialize: function() {

    },
   render: function(){
     var template = $('#story_template').html();
    this.template = _.template(template);
    $('#canvas_id').html(this.template());
   },

    test: function() {
   alert("delete"); 
        <!--  click .delete event not triggering -->
    },

    remove: function(){
     alert("how to remove the template");   
        <!-- how to remove template after rendering -->
    }


  });

var story_view = new StoryView();
```

Template:

```
<div id="story">
   <a href="#" class="story">click this story link to render into canvas_id but how to set event to remove?</a>
</div>

<div id="canvas_id"></div>

<script id="story_template" type="text/underscore">
"I want to make the x
    after this story clickable to remove the template
    but since it's not within the #story div (which
    is just a navbar in my real app), it's not working"
<span class="delete">X</span>



</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand why you can only listen to events on your view's el, you need to first understand how backbone.js *listens* to events.

In backbone.js events are [delegated](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (using jQuery or Zepto) to the view's `el`. In your case being that your view's `el` is `#story` your remove event isn't being triggered.

What you can do is when you click to render your template, you can reassign your view's el using [setElement](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) which will also move (re-delegate) the views delegated events to the new `el` ( (as [@muistooshort](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) pointed out).

For example

```
   render: function(){
     var template = $('#story_template').html();
    this.template = _.template(template);
    $('#canvas_id').html(this.template());
       this.setElement($('#canvas_id'));
   },
```

And in your remove event you can reassign your `el` back to the `#story` element.

update [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RRXnK/149/)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle and explanation.

Comment: @muistooshort your right, it is redundant, I modified my anwser accordingly.